# Print folder name where file originated from

Tags: java, substring

I'm trying to print a folder name where a file is stored.

Example: 
I have the file picture.jpg
Stored in the path C:\Users\Desktop\Foldername\picture.jpg

Is it possible to print "Foldername". I've tried a substring but that seems to rely on me hard-coding the character number in. EG:

```
System.out.println(path.substring(33, 38));
```

If my program was to be released, and the user had a different file path - this would offset the substring.

To select the file, my program has the following code

```
chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File(computerUsername+"\\Desktop\\Foldername"));
        chooser.setDialogTitle(choosertitle);
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(true);
```

Therefore, the below code prints out a nullpointexpection error.
    chooser.getPath().getName();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is [`java.io.File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/io/File.html). It has methods to transform paths.

```
System.out.println(new File(path).getParentFile().getName());
```

If you didn't have that, the way to do it "by hand" would be to look for path separator characters (`\`) and split around those.

Answer (score 2):

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Foldername\\picture.jpg");
String parentFolderName = file.getParentFile().getName();
```